# Data Grid Empty Despite Results

Tags: c#, list, datagrid, azure-cosmosdb, syncfusion

I know I'm doing something wrong here but I'm not sure what. I have the data grid below and some code to grab some documents from cosmosDB.

```
<SfButton @onclick="btnTest"></SfButton>
<SfGrid @ref="RequestGrid" DataSource="@requests" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" AllowPdfExport="true" AllowExcelExport="true" Locale="en-GB" Toolbar="@Toolbaritems">
    <GridEvents OnToolbarClick="ToolbarClickHandler" TValue="RequestRoot"></GridEvents>
    <GridPageSettings PageSize="5"></GridPageSettings>
    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(RequestRoot.id) HeaderText="ID" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" Width="10"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(RequestRoot.identityrequest.email) HeaderText="Email" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" Width="50"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(RequestRoot.identityrequest.status) HeaderText="Status" TextAlign="TextAlign.Left" Width="150"></GridColumn>
    </GridColumns>
</SfGrid>
<SfDialog Width="250px" IsModal="true" @bind-Visible="@IsVisible">
    <DialogEvents OnOverlayClick="@OnOverlayclick">
    </DialogEvents>
    <DialogTemplates>
        <Content> This is a modal dialog </Content>
    </DialogTemplates>
</SfDialog>
@code {
    private List<RequestRoot> requests = new List<RequestRoot>();
    public SfGrid<RequestRoot> RequestGrid;
    private List<Object> Toolbaritems = new List<Object>() { "Search", new ItemModel() { Text = "Add Request", TooltipText = "Add Request", PrefixIcon = "e-add", Id = "Click" }, "PdfExport", "WordExport", "ExcelExport" };
    bool IsVisible = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        IDocumentQuery<RequestRoot> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<RequestRoot>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("ID4S", "identityrequest"),
            new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 199, MaxBufferedItemCount = 100000 })
            .AsDocumentQuery();

        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            FeedResponse<RequestRoot> feedResponse = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<RequestRoot>();
            Console.WriteLine(feedResponse.Select(x => x.id));
            requests = feedResponse.ToList();
        }
        return;
    }
```

After this has run I can see `requests` has two items in it as expected however the table does not populate with any data and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue when the datasource has empty list and it will be resolved in the Service Pack release which is expected to be rolled out on or before mid of August 2020.

Until then you can declare the datasource property as null and then bind the actual value in the OnInitializedAsync method to resolve this issue. Refer the below code snippet.

```html
<SfGrid  DataSource="@requests">
..
</SfGrid>

@code {

private List<RequestRoot> requests = null;
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
requests = feedResponse.ToList();
}
}
```